# How do you get a tkinter window to close automatically after a few seconds delay?

Tags: python, tkinter, wait

I have a tkinter window, `root`, which should close after a few seconds delay. Here is the code I currently have for my window:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
def WaitAndClose():
    global root
    #close root after a few seconds
Button(root, text='Close', command=WaitAndClose).pack()
mainloop()
```

**EDIT:** root.after(,) was the command that worked.

Comment: read up on the `after` and `destroy` methods that are available on every widget.

Comment: @Azxdreuwa See my answer for an implementation that should work

Answer (score 5):

The following should close the tkinter window `root` (change as applicable) after 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds):

```
root.after(5000, root.destroy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

jha=Tk()

jha.title("auto close window")

jha.geometry("750x600")

jha.after(5000,lambda:jha.destroy())

jha.mainloop()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.